# How to map a list of variable length to object properties?

Tags: c#, string, properties, mapping, iteration

In this scenario I have an object `Foo` that contains some string properties with this naming convention: `Foo.Bar1`, `Foo.Bar2`, etc...

I want to use a list of strings of unknown length to map to each `Bar`*(n)* property:

```
public class Mapper()
{      
  public Foo MapToFoo(List<string> list)
  {
    var Foo = new Foo();
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
      //? Here is some psudo-code/logic of what I am trying to achieve:
      //Bar*X* = item
      //X++
    }
    return Foo;
  }
}

public class Foo
{
  public string Bar1 { get; set; }
  public string Bar2 { get; set; }
  public string Bar3 { get; set; }
}
```

*I recognize I could just add `public List<string> Bars` and get rid of the `Bar1`, `Bar2`, `Bar3`. And while that may be the preferred solution, in my particular case it would require a lot of changes to a tightly coupled legacy project.*

Is there a way to do this? If so, in a way that the mapping would never look for a *BarX* that doesn't exist (i.e. `Bar4` in this case)?

Comment: It is possible ,you will have to use relection for that

Comment: You have many unanswered requirements. What if list has more strings than Foo has properties? What if there are more Foo properties than strings? Reflected properties do not guarantee order, is it ok for string 2 to set Bar3 value? I suggest you don't do this at all, build an [Adapter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) to bridge the legacy code.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can't use anything like  `Bars`, you probably need to use reflection, something like this:

```
public class Mapper
{
    public Foo MapToFoo(List<string> list)
    {
        var Foo = new Foo();
        var props = typeof(Foo).GetProperties()
                               .Where(pi => pi.Name.StartsWith("Bar"))
                               .OrderBy(pi => pi.Name).ToList();

        for (int i = 0; i < Math.Min(list.Count, props.Count); i++)
            props[i].SetValue(Foo, list[i]);

        return Foo;
    }
}
```

But perhaps using a `Dictionary<string, string>` for the property names and the values is more suitable:

```
var mapper = new Mapper();

var values = new Dictionary<string, String>();
values["Bar1"] = "A";
values["Bar2"] = "B";
values["Bar3"] = "C";

var foo = mapper.MapToFoo(values);

...
public class Mapper
{
    public Foo MapToFoo(Dictionary<string, string> values)
    {
        var Foo = new Foo();
        foreach (var item in values)
        {
            var prop = typeof(Foo).GetProperty(item.Key);

            if (prop != null)
                prop.SetValue(Foo, item.Value);
        }

        return Foo;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use reflection to achieve the same. Assuming that your properties are named Bar1, Bar2, Bar3... and so on you could do the following.

```
    public Foo MapToFoo(List<string> list)
    {
        var Foo = new Foo();
        var propertyName = "Bar";
        int index = 1;
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            var property = Foo.GetType().GetProperty(string.Format("{0}{1}", propertyName, index));
            if(property != null)
            {
                property.SetValue(Foo, item);
            }
            index++;
        }
        return Foo;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I mean you can get all the properties using reflection:

```
PropertyInfo[] properties = type.GetProperties();

foreach (PropertyInfo property in properties)
{
   //Store the values in an sort them
}
```

This does **NOT** guarantee order so you will have to sort them.

Just because you can, doesn't mean you should. You should ask yourself "Why am I doing this?" and "Is there a simpler/more maintainable solution?"

Answer (score 0):

You can use reflection:

```
public class Mapper()
{      
  public Foo MapToFoo(List<string> list)
  { 
      Foo f = new Foo();
      var bars =  f.GetType().GetProperties();
      int i=0;
      foreach (var item in list)
      {
            bars[i++].SetValue(f, item);
            if(i==bars.Length)
                break;
      }
      return f;
   }
}

public class Foo
{
  public string Bar1 { get; set; }
  public string Bar2 { get; set; }
  public string Bar3 { get; set; }
}
```